# Register Jackson with wink using spring integration

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

I have developed a small RESTful web service using apache wink.  I am using the spring integration module and define my rest services there.  I am trying to add JSON support and have run into a small bug.  When I try to return a java list with only 1 element in it, wink returns just the object instead of an array with 1 object in it.  It seems this is a bug with the default JSON providers that come with wink.

So I have attempted to use Jackson as the wink JSON provider.  I have found documentation of how to define a WinkApplication and set Jackson as the provider.  This never gets used in my app and I believe it's because the winkCoreContext-server.xml file defines a Registrar instead of using the Application I defined.

Can anyone point me to some documentation or an example of how to use Jackson together with the spring integration module of Apache Wink?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a post that answered my question:

http://agoodexample.tumblr.com/

I needed to extend the wink-spring-integration Registrar class and add a setter for singletons then load my jackson provider through a reference.